# Copying sub folders from a folder to another folder using R

Tags: r, file, file-manipulation

I have a folder called 6a in my working directory which has four subfolders. I want to create another new folder called 6b in my working directory and copy the subfolders of 6a into 6b. I did this

```
 dir.create(paste0(getwd(),"/6b"), showWarnings = FALSE) # Create a folder 6b


 file.copy(from = paste0(getwd(), "/6a/"), 
           to = paste0(getwd(), paste0(getwd(),"/6b"), recursive = T)
```

When I do this it copies the entire folder 6a inside 6b instead of copying the sub-folders of 6b in 6a. How can I fix it?

Comment: This is not right: `paste0(getwd(), paste0("6b")` .

Comment: Have you tried with `"/6a/."`?